# I can not make a repetition of the animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

How can I do to move to a position 100,100 to coordinate 100,200, and then returned without animation initial position and start moving again?

This is the code I am using:

```
SKAction *ac = [SKAction moveToY:self.size.height+StartPanel.size.height duration:0.7];
[StartPanel runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:ac]];
```

Comment: What have you got so far? How are you doing the animation? Can you include your current code?

Comment: SKAction *ac = [SKAction moveToY:self.size.height+StartPanel.size.height duration:0.7];
[StartPanel runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:ac]];

Comment: I've edited your question to include that, and the fact that you are using sprite kit. That was really important information that you should have included in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the panel back to it's starting position.
At the moment you're just sending it to "self.size.height+StartPanel.size.height" but not back.

Try this:

```
SKAction *ac = [SKAction moveToY:self.size.height+StartPanel.size.height duration:0.7];
SKAction *acBack = [SKAction moveToY:self.size.height duration:0];
SKAction *sequenceOfActions = [SKAction sequence:@[ac, acBack]];
[StartPanel runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:sequenceOfActions]];
```